# Caching expensive result in Redis using Celery (For use in flask app)

Tags: python, docker, flask, redis, celery

My Problem: My homepage has one particularly expensive process on initialization (takes 10-15 seconds to complete, consists of various SQL queries and returns on JSON object). I want this process to be run on a scheduler, with the result being stored in Redis. The problem is, I don't know how to store/send commands to Redis, as from my perspective celery is acting as a black box, and redis resides within that black box.

Background: I have stack consisting of Flask, Celery, and Redis. I have the Flask portion on one docker container, while I have the Celery tasks being run on a different docker container. I use Redis as my broker. Now, I just finished converting my app to using this setup, and before I just had the client submitting routes to different flask waitress workers, and like now, this process would just take forever to finish. Its not really blocking anything, but i want it to load faster.

Code Example: What I have

```
app = Celery('tasks', broker='redis://redis:6379/0', backend='redis://redis:6379/0')

@app.task(bind=True, name='expensiveTask')
def expensiveTask(self, args=None):

    self.update_state(state='PENDING')
    returnVal = tH.getDefaultFailureResponse()

    try:
        returnVal = tH.expensiveFunction()
        self.update_state(state='COMPLETE')

    except:
        self.update_state(state='FAILED')

    return returnVal`
```

Code Example: What I want

```
app = Celery('tasks', broker='redis://redis:6379/0', backend='redis://redis:6379/0')

@app.task(bind=True, name='expensiveTask')
def expensiveTask(self, args=None):

    self.update_state(state='PENDING')
    returnVal = tH.getDefaultFailureResponse()

    try:
        if(constant key to expensive result exists in redis):
            returnVal = redis[constantKey]
        else:
            returnVal = tH.expensiveFunction()
        self.update_state(state='COMPLETE')

    except:
        self.update_state(state='FAILED')

    return returnVal

#should run ever x amount of time to stay updated (10 minutes)
@app.task(bind=True, name='scheduledExpensiveTask')
def scheduledExpensiveTask(self, args=None):

    redis[constantKey] = tH.expensiveFunction()
```

Don't worry about informing me how to implement celery beat, that is a different problem and I want to focus on the (hopefully) singular question above.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I answered my question I think, it should look something like this

```
import redis

app = Celery('tasks', broker='redis://redis:6379/0', backend='redis://redis:6379/0')

@app.task(bind=True, name='expensiveTask')
def expensiveTask(self, args=None):

    self.update_state(state='PENDING')
    returnVal = tH.getDefaultFailureResponse()

    try:
        
        redisConn = redis.from_url('redis://redis:6379/0')

        if(redisConn.exists(constantKey)):
            returnVal = redisConn.get(constantKey)
        else:
            returnVal = tH.expensiveFunction()
        self.update_state(state='COMPLETE')

    except:
        self.update_state(state='FAILED')

    return returnVal

#should run ever x amount of time to stay updated (10 minutes)
@app.task(bind=True, name='scheduledExpensiveTask')
def scheduledExpensiveTask(self, args=None):

    redisConn = redis.from_url('redis://redis:6379/0')
    expensiveResult = tH.expensiveFunction()
    redistConn.set(constantKey, expensiveResult)
```

Treat this more as pseudo code, because you still have to serialize your data, your URL might be different, your setup, you want to handle exceptions, but i think this should work just fine